# Error 400 Bad Request when querying for list of projects

Tags: api, asana

I am trying to query the list of projects available to a user with the Asana API as shown in their documentation under the title "Show all projects in a workspace or organization", but I am encountering a 400 Error.

The error message details being returned are:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Missing required `team` field"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the following endpoint except that I am using my actual workspace ID:

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/workspaces/14916/projects

The documentation for this example does not mention a team field, and the only reference to the team field applies to create-only operations.  Does anyone have an idea as to what my issue is?

Comment: How are you querying ? Can you describe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having additional information, it sounds like the query might actually be using the wrong HTTP verb - maybe POST? - rather than a GET.

Can you show the exact request you make, how you make it? An example with curl is usually a good common denominator, but code would work as well.

Comment: I was sending a POST request via the PHP Curl Library.  Changing my code to a GET request resolved the issue.  Thank you for your help.